# Display Search Parameter As Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently i facing a problem to display search parameter in 'Like' statement as 1 new column. my SQL code is as below:

```
 Select A.Description from table A Where A.Description like ('%Battery%')
```

The Output:

```
Description 
12V Battery
 9V Battery
 5V Battery
```

The Output i want was:

```
Description   Description_1
12V Battery   Battery
 9V Battery   Battery
 5V Battery   Battery
```

Isn't possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b96f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Description ) AS
          SELECT '9V Battery' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '12V Battery' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '24V Battery' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Torch' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Rope' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH search_terms AS (
            SELECT 'Battery' AS search_term FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Torch' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT A.Description,
       s.search_term AS Description_1
FROM   table_name A
       INNER JOIN
       search_terms s
       ON ( A.Description LIKE '%' || search_term || '%' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b96f/1/0)**:

```
| DESCRIPTION | DESCRIPTION_1 |
|-------------|---------------|
|  9V Battery |       Battery |
| 12V Battery |       Battery |
| 24V Battery |       Battery |
|       Torch |         Torch |
```

Or, if you are only using a single search term, you can replace the named sub-query with a [bind variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch34.htm):

```
SELECT A.Description,
       :search_term AS Description_1
FROM   table_name A
WHERE  A.Description LIKE '%' || :search_term || '%'
```

Comment: after compare 3 of this method i found that union more reliable. However it take a long time to query out all the thing i want.

Answer (score 0):

how about including it in the `SELECT` statement?

```
SELECT  A.Description ,
       'Battery' AS Description_1
FROM    table A 
WHERE   A.Description LIKE '%Battery%'
```

Comment: Isn't possible to do so without hard code the 'Battery'? I wish to display the search parameter that put inside the 'like'.

Comment: in the first place, how did you put `battery` in your `LIKE` clause?

Comment: same as display on above. Because i have a lot of search parameter which i join them by using 'OR' statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

```
with tab as
(select 'Battery' FILTER
   from dual)
Select A.Description, B.filter
  from table_name A, tab B 
 Where A.Description like '%'|| b.filter ||'%';
```

Output

```
| DESCRIPTION |  FILTER |
|-------------|---------|
|  9V Battery | Battery |
| 12V Battery | Battery |
| 24V Battery | Battery |
```

Put the filter in query `select 'Battery' FILTER from dual` .